# unable to set variable consistantly

Tags: mysql, variables, set, case

I am unable to to consistently set and query a variable @imgpath
After getting the value from it, i see it is not consistant
With when `left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1) in("C")`

for instance, the concat returns a "0" under this section
The parsed data from `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)`
looks like this:

```
C5
C178
```

Further down in my script, I query @image path like

```
If(substring(@imgpath,1,1) = "C",dosmthing,dosomthing)
```

Many times this will return "0"

I think it is either how or where I am setting @imgpath

If I don't assign it to a variable using THEN, it works normally (correctly)

```
select pa.name,
case
  when left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1) in("B") then  @imgpath :=
    if(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) < "B16",3464,101)
  when left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1) in("C") then @imgpath :=
     if(length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)) < 3,
       concat(left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1), "0", 
              right(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1)),SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1))
  when left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1) = "J" then @imgpath :=
    if(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) < "J19",3464,101)
  when left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),1) = "O" then @imgpath := 101
  when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) < 116 then @imgpath := 3464
  when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pa.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) >= 116 then @imgpath := 101
 end as "temp",
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want.  The MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) *explicitly* states:

> In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate
>   @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @a='test';
> mysql> SELECT @a,(@a:=20) FROM tbl_name;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

In other words, you cannot expect to use the variable in a different expression.